# how to add days to date range elastic search in c#?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I want to do something like that:

```
var client = new ElasticClient();

client.Search<MyDocument>(s => s
    .Query(q => q
        .DateRange(dr => dr
            .Field(f => f.AgreementCancelDate)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals("now-30d/d")
        )
    )
);
```

but instead of "now" add some date field.

for example to check if expireDate is greater more than 30 days from register date :

```
.Field(f => f.ExipreDate)
            .GreaterThanOrEquals("doc.RegisterDate+30d/d")
```

Answer (score 0):

In elastic search there is no way to compare two fields of a document.

You can use [runtime_mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/runtime-search-request.html) in latest elastic search version

```
{
  "runtime_mappings": {
    "daysToExpireFromRegisteration": {
      "type": "long",
      "script": {
        "source": "emit((doc['ExipreDate'].value.millis -doc['RegisterDate'].value.millis)/ 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24)"
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
     "range": {
       "daysToExpireFromRegisteration": {
         "gte": 10
       }
     }
  }
}
```

To improve performance you can also index the difference and query on it